# Angle of a Star Inscribed in a Circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, angle

I don't even know where to start on this: In the figure, point O is the center of the circle, points A, B, C, D and E all lie on the circle, and both segment AD and CE go through point O.  Angle BEC measures 28 degrees, and ADB measures 37 degrees.  Find the measure of ACE.
[The Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKLEb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

By the *inscribed angle theorem*, $\;\widehat{ACE}=\frac12\widehat{AOE}$,  $\;\widehat{AOB}=2\widehat{ABD}$, $\;\widehat{BOCB}=2\widehat{BEC}$.

Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, I think I figured it out. Thanks.